# Send httpclient post inside another httpclient post in Angular7

Tags: rxjs, angular7, angular-httpclient

I have two problems, the first one is that I want to send data to server with httpclient post method, and if everything is ok I want to send the other post request. I have the first table (codeRole, nameRole) and in the second table I have (action, nameAction), in the same form the user can create a role and link this role to one or many actions and all of that is enregistred in a table roleAction(id, codeRole, nameRole, action, nameAction), and i dont know how to do that with Angular, waiting for my role to be inserted and then insert the role actions one by one in the third table.

my code could be like that:

```
<form
      fxLayout="column"
      fxFlexAlign="center center"
      fxLayoutGap="10px"
      #newRoleF="ngForm"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmitRoleF(newRoleF); newRoleF.resetForm({})"
      [hidden]="!showRoleForm"
    >
      <!-- code role -->
      <mat-label> Code Role</mat-label>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          required
          name="codeRole"
          ngModel
        >
      </mat-form-field>
      <!-- ******** fin code role *********** -->

      <!-- nom role -->
      <mat-label> Nom de role </mat-label>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          required
          name="nomRole"
          ngModel              
        >
      </mat-form-field>
      <!-- ******** fin nom role *********** -->

      <!-- Role actions -->
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Actions</mat-label>
        <mat-select name="roleAction" ngModel multiple required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let action of droitActions" [value]="action">{{action.nom_action}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <!-- ******** fin role actions *********** -->
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <button type="submit"
                mat-raised-button
                color="primary"
                [disabled]="newRoleF.invalid"
        >
          Enregistrer
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

In the .ts file

```
onSubmitRoleF(newRoleF: NgForm) {
const val = newRoleF.value;
const params = {};
params['code_role'] = val.codeRole;
params['nom_role'] = val.nomRole;
params['role_action'] = val.roleAction
  // first add the role
  this.droitsS.addRole(params)
    .subscribe(
      (resultat) => {
        // once the role added, start to add the role actions one by one, if the user choose two 
        // actions, I must do two httpclient post to add them
      },
      (error => {
       console.log(error);
      })
    );
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
async onSubmitRoleF(newRoleF: NgForm) {
const val = newRoleF.value;
const params = {};
params['code_role'] = val.codeRole;
params['nom_role'] = val.nomRole;
params['role_action'] = val.roleAction
  // first add the role
  const result = await this.droitsS.addRole(params)
   .toPromise().catch(err => console.log(err)
  // do your logic and if needed just do it again
const secoundResult = await this.myrequest().toPromise().catch(err => console.log(err)

    );
```

like I wrote, use async await to make it simple and easier to track.
gl

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand right, you have one call to an http service followed by N calls to another http service, where N is the number of actions chosen by the user.

Assuming you have an array holding your actions, e.g. `myActions`, and that the second service is named `saveActions`, then you can try something like this

```
this.droitsS.addRole(params) // call to the first service
.pipe( 
   concatMap(() => {
      const saveActionObservables = myActions.map(action => this.saveAction(action));
      return forkJoin(saveActionObservables)
   })
)
.subscribe(
  (resultat) => {
    // here you do anything you want with the result
  },
  (error => {
   console.log(error);
  })
)
```

What happens here is the following. As soon as the first call returns, then you enter into the function specified as parameter of `concatMap`. This function does 2 things:

1. first it creates an Array of Observables with the code
   `saveActionObservables = myActions.map(action => this.saveAction(action))`; each of these Observables represent a
   future call to the second service
2. then it fires all these service calls in parallel using the `forkJoin` function

You may follow different strategies to handle this case, this is just one. More details can be found in [this article](https://medium.com/@enrico.piccinin/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).